# Site logo in header ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following image tag that I am trying to add to my site.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "core")" class="navbar-brand">
    <img src="~/images/core.png" title="core" alt="additional title" />
</a>
```

I've tried to add this tag in both head as well as body tags of my _Layout.cshtml page and it ends up just below the header.Where should I add the tag so that it appears at the top left corner of the site?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>@ViewData["Title"] - core</title>

<environment names="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
@Html.ApplicationInsightsJavaScript(TelemetryConfiguration)
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="core" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">core</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">  

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2017 - core Inc. - core</p>
    </footer>
</div>

<environment names="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal">
    </script>
    <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

In the body but this would place the logo below the head.

```
<body>
 <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "core")" class="navbar-brand">
    <img src="~/images/core.png" title="core" alt="additional title" />
</a>     
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      .
      .
      .
```

[image]

Comment: Add it to the head and use CSS to position it at top left corner of the page.  You can use margins or CSS absolute and relative positions to place the icon. Floats too might help. Would help if you can post some more code.

Comment: Can you share the full `HTML`? or at least the header part?

Comment: You wouldn't be adding to the <head> section, that's for meta information that only the browser cares about. You'll want to look inside the <body> tag, in whatever element is the black bar in your image. Use the developer tools to highlight the element to find out which it is if you are unsure.

Comment: @inquisitive_mind I meant the `header` not the `head`, nothing added to the `head` appears in the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself.It needs to go inside the `<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">`

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "core")" class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="~/images/core.png" title="core" alt="" />
    </a> 
    <div class="container">         
        <div class="navbar-header">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:
position:relative
top: (add here the amount of pixels)

another option is to use
position: absolute and change the logo's place, you may also send me a private msg and I'll try to help you more with more code/direct link to your site